# How it is possible to stretch the image manually to our required pixel position

Tags: android

How it is possible to stretch the image manually to our required pixel position.in my android application i want to stretch my image to the specified position by dragging the end points of it.can anybody suggest me how to do this............

Answer (score 1):

You can use an imageview with the attribute

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

This will make the image to fit the bounds of the imageview.

To modify the image on click or touch, you will need add a ontouchlistener to the view. And on the based on the view getTop and and getLeft, you will need to set the layout params of the view to increase or decrease the size.

Or you will need to extend a view and override the onDraw method, in that method you can use the canvas.drawBitmap method to specify the size of the bitmap.

Either way you will need to use the onTouchListener.

Comment: yes u are right but we want to manually set the image with the mousepointer